# How to print nodes to thermal printer - JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx

I want to print nodes with their content (`ImageView`, `Label`, `VBox` etc)  to a thermal printer.
I already have the nodes ready and set to fit the size of an 80mm paper.

The problem is when I try to create a custom paper size to fit the 80mm paper size of my thermal printer I get all the content shifted to the right.

However, that only happens when I change the `height` of the paper.

This is my printing code

```
public void printImage(Node node) {

        PrinterJob job = PrinterJob.createPrinterJob();

        Paper paper = PrintHelper.createPaper("Roll80", 80, 270, Units.MM);
        PageLayout pageLayout = job.getPrinter().createPageLayout(paper, PageOrientation.PORTRAIT, 0, 0, 0, 0);

        double scale = 0.791;

        node.getTransforms().add(new Scale(scale, scale));

        if (job != null) {
            boolean success = printerJob.printPage(pageLayout, node);
            if (success) {
                job.endJob();
                System.exit(0);
            }
        }
    }
```

ٌResults when I set the paper height to less than 310 or more than 340
Example: `Paper paper = PrintHelper.createPaper("Roll80", 80, 270, Units.MM);`
[results1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pBOhh.png)

ٌResults when I set the paper height to 310 or 340 or more than 560
Example: `Paper paper = PrintHelper.createPaper("Roll80", 80, 590, Units.MM);`
[results2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ujwkD.png) *Img is much hiegher than captured.

Note: 
When I adjust the width to more than 100 I still can get the height to less than 230 with no problems but still, I want my page width to be 80mm and the height to the same height of my receipt(Nodes).

PrintHelper method:

```
package com.sun.javafx.print;

import javafx.print.JobSettings;
import javafx.print.Paper;
import javafx.print.PaperSource;
import javafx.print.PrintResolution;
import javafx.print.Printer;

/**
 * An internal class which provides a way for implementation code to
 * access to package level protected constructors (etc).
 * All entry points to the printing API need to ensure this class is
 * loaded and initialized.
 */
public class PrintHelper {
    private static PrintAccessor printAccessor;

    static {
        forceInit(Printer.class);
    }

    private PrintHelper() {
    }

    public static PrintResolution createPrintResolution(int fr, int cfr) {
        return printAccessor.createPrintResolution(fr, cfr);
    }

    public static Paper createPaper(String paperName,
                             double paperWidth,
                             double paperHeight,
                             Units units) {
        return printAccessor.createPaper(paperName, paperWidth, paperHeight, units);
    }

    public static PaperSource createPaperSource(String name) {
        return printAccessor.createPaperSource(name);
    }

    public static JobSettings createJobSettings(Printer printer) {
        return printAccessor.createJobSettings(printer);
    }

    public static Printer createPrinter(PrinterImpl impl) {
        return printAccessor.createPrinter(impl);
    }

    public static PrinterImpl getPrinterImpl(Printer printer) {
        return printAccessor.getPrinterImpl(printer);
    }

    public static void setPrintAccessor(final PrintAccessor newAccessor) {
        if (printAccessor != null) {
            throw new IllegalStateException();
        }

        printAccessor = newAccessor;
    }

    public interface PrintAccessor {
        PrintResolution createPrintResolution(int fr, int cfr);

        Paper createPaper(String paperName,
                                          double paperWidth,
                                          double paperHeight,
                                          Units units);

        PaperSource createPaperSource(String name);

        JobSettings createJobSettings(Printer printer);

        Printer createPrinter(PrinterImpl impl);

        PrinterImpl getPrinterImpl(Printer printer);
    }

    private static void forceInit(final Class<?> classToInit) {
        try {
            Class.forName(classToInit.getName(), true,
                          classToInit.getClassLoader());
        } catch (final ClassNotFoundException e) {
            throw new AssertionError(e);  // Can't happen
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please edit your question and show the code for the PrintHelper.createPaper method.

Comment: PrintHelper.createPaper is a master method within Java.

Comment: I’m guessing it’s the `com.sun.javafx.print.PrintHelper` class, then?

Comment: Yes its that's the one.

Comment: I have updated the post with the full code for the PrintHelper method.

Comment: What happens if you don’t create a PageLayout at all, and just call `printerJob.printPage(node)`?

Comment: I haven't tested what would happen if I print the node without the `PageLayout` on the thermal printer, but when I save it as a PDF it gets the default PDF paper size, meaning if the receipt is long it will exceed the PDF paper height.